# Why Coil is not loading Images from Repository?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am using Coil library to load images from Firebase in my project. Small Images are able to load successfully but large size images are not loading. I have tried all ways to make it happen but not getting why these are not loading. This is my code

```
@Composable
fun AdvertisementBanner(advertiseList: List<Categories>) {
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(200.dp)
 ) {
    Banner(advertiseList = advertiseList)
   }
 }



  @Composable
 fun Banner(advertiseList: List<Categories>) {
  LazyRow(
    modifier = Modifier.height(200.dp),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(3.dp)
   ) {
    items(advertiseList.size) {
        if (advertiseList[it].type == "AdvertisementBanner") {
            BannerItem(
                backgroundColor = Color.White,
                advertiseList[it].url!!
             )
          }
       }
     }
  }

 @Composable
 fun BannerItem(
 backgroundColor: Color,
  imagePainter: String
  ){
  Card(
    modifier = Modifier
        .width(300.dp)
        .padding(5.dp),
    elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(
        defaultElevation = 5.dp
    ),
    colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
        containerColor = Color.White
      )
     ) {
        LoadImages(imagePainter)
   }
 }

 @Composable
 fun LoadImages(imagesUrl: String?) {
    AsyncImage(
        model = imagesUrl, contentDescription = "repository images", contentScale = 
   ContentScale.Fit, modifier = Modifier.width(300.dp)
     )
   }
```

Please tell me how do i fix it.

Comment: You can debug the coil function using a custom `val imageLoader = LocalContext.current.imageLoader.newBuilder().logger(DebugLogger()).build()`

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti yes I debug the coil function and I got a unknownhostException   [ java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "banner.caratlane.com": No address associated with hostname ]. How do i fix it now

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I googled about the Exception and found that its al because of emulator. I tried to run the app in my device and its working fine now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
val painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
            ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current).data(data = imgUrl)
                .apply(block = fun ImageRequest.Builder.() {
                    placeholder(placeholder)
                    scale(Scale.FILL)
                }).build()
        )
        Image(
            painter = painter,
            contentDescription = contentDescription,
            mod.fillMaxSize(),
            contentScale = scale
        )
```

I use `coil` like this to load bigger images. give a a try, hope it works.

Comment: Thanks , my exception is resolved by @Gabriele suggestion , still i voting Up for u .

Comment: So kind of you. it will increase my motivation of helping others.